# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on CollectionView Cell not working

Tags: ios, object, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UICollectionView (horizontal Layout) with multiple Cells. Only one Cell should be shown on the Device and after 4 seconds the next cell fading in and the old should go off the screen. This works perfectly. I´m using a NSTimer for the automatic animations.

My Problem is, that i want to stop this animation when the User touches (not click!) one of the cells. So i made a UISwipeGestureRecognizer like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *collectionViewSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.collectionView action:@selector(didTouchCell:)];
collectionViewSwipe.delegate = self;
collectionViewSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:collectionViewSwipe];
}

- (void)didTouchCell: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {

[self.collectionViewTimer invalidate];
}
```

But the "didTouchCell" never gets called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the CollectionView was on top of a UIScrollView so i had to implement this Method in my Controller:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return true;
}
```